# How to get Class propertyName to create lable?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

how can i learn propert to create page form in asp.net

```
class MyClass
{
    public int id { get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set;}
}
```

ForExample : (To generate programmatically Asp.net forms)

```
 void SetRecursiveTextBoxAndLabels()
        {

            Label lbl;
                 MyClass eng = new MyClass();
                Type typ = eng.GetType();
                PropertyInfo[] properties = typ.GetProperties();
                for( int i =0;  i<properties.Length; i++)
                {
                    lbl = new Label();
                    lbl.ID = properties[i].Name;
                    lbl.Text = properties[i].Name;
                    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(lbl);
                }
            }
        }
```

But it is not run correctly:( loading is too slow... By the way i didn't create classıs in real time . i ama using linqtoSql . You can talk about solution wthi the base of linqtosql...

Comment: The code you've provided should run relatively quickly. Have you provided us a shortened down version? Does SetRecursiveTextBoxAndLabels() get called multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Cache Reflection Results (Class Properties)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204748/cache-reflection-results-class-properties) and see if caching your reflection calls would help.  As [GenericTypeTea](https://stackoverflow.com/users/44269/generictypetea) suggested, calling this multiple times is probably the cause of any delay you are seeing.  Here is also a link to a [Fast Reflection Library](http://weblogs.asp.net/jeffreyzhao/archive/2009/01/27/fast-reflection-library.aspx) that may be a way to let someone else implement and debug the caching code for you.