# I am using reflection to get property names and values in ASP.NET need some advice on optimization

Tags: c#, asp.net, optimization, reflection

I am using reflection to get property (as in {get; set} properties) names and their value. I would like to optimize this reflection. I don't have access to the code of the client classes I am using the reflection on, but after figuring out the property names of the class involved I will be reusing the same properties again and again.

I am doing this in an ASP.NET application and so I was thinking of storing some cached results in the Application (HttpContext.Current.Application) so the first user would have the primary increased performance load, but as requests scale other users can use the cached results of the first user.

- NHibernate
- [Marc Gravell's HyperDescripter](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/HyperPropertyDescriptor.aspx)

Can somone give me a very laymans explanation of if Marc Gravel's solution is appropriate here, or if something like NHibernate is good for this situation? Or should I just cache the results of aquiring the property names in the class via reflection in a list and then use that when I need to enumerate property names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HyperDescriptor is designed for the specific purpose of fitting *inside the ComponentModel* API. If you don't use that, it may be overkill. Just caching the data inside a static generic type can be pretty effective, using a static constructor to populate the data. By which I mean: store the data per-T:

```
public static class PropertyCache<T>
{
    public static SomeType SomeName { get { return someField; } }
    static PropertyCache() {
        // init someField
    }
}
...
var foo = PropertyCache<Foo>.SomeName;
```

Comment: I think this guy might know what best suits Marc Gravell's HyperDescripter :P

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use Application Cache in asp.net environment?

Comment: @František no, not particularly. It it unlikely that the types you are interested in changes much during execution, and this is direct: very fast and efficient;

Comment: This is elegant, If I also cached the "handle" to the value i.e. `typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyName)` and then passed my instance into a GetValue call on this stored object would any reflection be reduced on the value capture side of things?

Comment: @Marc - (I could use the above method to cache the property names using reflection in the constructor once, and probably manage it via a List since the number of properties is variable. My last comment deals with handling the access of the values) - Just making sure I am understanding your usage correctly.

Comment: @Joshua exactly. For access of the values, you can pre-compile delegate accessors via either the Expression API, Delegate.CreateDelegate, or ILGenerator

Answer (score 0):

You answered yourself.

"Or should I just cache the results of aquiring the property names in the class via reflection in a list and then use that when I need to enumerate property names?"

I implemented this using a hashtable.

Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8038933/497982