# how to cache reflection in C#

Tags: c#, reflection, system.reflection

Hello there
I am familiar with reflection quite a bit, I have been through loads of examples and I know how it works and for what purpose we can use it. But I didn't get any examples of caching the reflection, neither do I know what does it mean. And somehow I have to use caching of reflection in of the projects that I am doing.

Therefore, I would be obliged if some one can briefly explain this concept as well as give some examples of it, a link to existing examples would also be appreciated. And please also describe the reflection of attributes as well as its caching. Thanks in advance.

Regards 
Umair

Comment: You don't know What it is, you don't know Why  but still you _have to_ cache something?

Comment: this Thread will help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204748/cache-reflection-results-class-properties

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5668569/23354

Comment: @henk Holterman: There is a tip for you Sir, if you are knowledgeable please share your knowledge don't degrade people. You completely misunderstood the question, I never said that I don't know reflection. The point was caching the reflection, and I don't want to bother people unnecessarily, I googled it but couldn't find something useful.

Comment: I didn't intend to degrade you but I was (and am) critical of the question. The lack of detail (how is the metadat used?) makes it hard/impossible to answer. See below, just 2 attempts based on a lot of guesswork.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would cache it like you would anything else:

```
 var cache = new Dictionary<Type, IEnumerable<Attribute>>();

 // obj is some object
 var type = obj.GetType();
 var attributes = type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyAttribute), true);
 cache.Add(type, attributes);
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest not caching the reflection (hehe) because it is (of course) done by the runtime. If you mean to reduce lookup time and perhaps dynamic invocation overhead

1. Just hold a reference to the MethodInfo/PropertyInfo object to call
2. transform the reflected methods into Expressions. I suggest using DLINQ in order not to reinvent the wheel. See here for more pointers [Parsing a string C# LINQ expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3782538/parsing-a-string-c-linq-expression)

And whatever you do: don't complicate things by optimizing prematurely.

Comment: Reflection is not cached excessively. If you do a lot of meta-programming (in particular, common in library development), effective caching of reflection can make all the difference. Oh, and `Expression` is not any more optimized than `MethodInfo` - it is only when you compile it to a *strongly typed delegate* that it becomes useful.