# Are Properties.Settings cached?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms

I thought of reading `Properties.Settings` into fields and then using those fields for performance reasons, because [Properties.Settings uses reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.applicationsettingsbase) However, maybe those values are cached therefore there's no point in that.

So, are Properties.Settings cached?

Comment: Reflection is also cached by the way.

Comment: @DavidG Do you have a source for that? If so, that's the answer.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's an answer, just an interesting point. My real point though, would be how much of a performance benefit do you get from caching these values anyway? Is it worth the time you are spending on it? I usually refer people to this: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: @DavidG According to [Marc Gravell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669272/how-to-cache-reflection-in-c-sharp#comment6470508_5669423) in certain cases "effective caching of reflection can make all the difference.".

Comment: Yes, it can help if you are doing a LOT of reflection. But if you call these sparingly, it will make no difference at all and you have just wasted time worrying about it.

Comment: Also bear in mind that comment was written 8 years ago, things may have improved since then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Remarks** section of `ApplicationSettingsBase.Reload` method documentation refers caching.

> The Reload method clears the currently cached property values, causing a reload of 
>   these values from persistent storage when they are subsequently accessed. This method 
>   performs the following actions:
>
> - It clears the currently cached properties by clearing the collection represented by the PropertyValues property.
> - It raises the PropertyChanged event for every member of the Properties collection.
>
> Reload contrasts with Reset in that the former will load the last set of saved application settings values, whereas the latter will load the saved default values.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.applicationsettingsbase.reload?view=netframework-4.8